# Crash on click using lambda

Tags: android, lambda

Using below code snippet i got some error(Follow logs).

```
(findViewById(R.id.btn_verify)).setOnClickListener(view -> {
            doSomething();
}
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: interface not implemented
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Added below code in project level gradel and its works.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```